# How to implement long press (tap & hold) using angular in iphone ,safari

Tags: angular, typescript, hammer.js

I have tried hammerjs press,pressup events,pointerup,pointerdown events.These works in chrome and android perfectly but not working in iphone and safari.Also tried to use hostlisener event but not working in safari.Any other feasible solution available?